React Native Background Location Tracking not working on Samsung Devices with Android 14
So the issue is that this code works fine on everyother device and fetches the results but when using Samsung devices with android 14 it doesn't. It will still provide locations when in foreground but as soon as it gets moved to background it stops providing location updates.
CODE
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    PermissionsAndroid,
    Platform,
    Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import BackgroundService from 'react-native-background-actions';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

export default function App() {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState({});

    const sleep = (time) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));

    const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            try {
                const fineLocationGranted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    {
                        title: 'Fine Location Permission',
                        message: 'This app needs access to your precise location.',
                        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                        buttonPositive: 'OK',
                    }
                );

                if (fineLocationGranted !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    Alert.alert('Permission Denied', 'Fine location permission is required.');
                    return false;
                }

                const coarseLocationGranted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    {
                        title: 'Coarse Location Permission',
                        message: 'This app needs access to your approximate location.',
                        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                        buttonPositive: 'OK',
                    }
                );

                if (coarseLocationGranted !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    Alert.alert('Permission Denied', 'Coarse location permission is required.');
                    return false;
                }

                const backgroundLocationGranted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                    {
                        title: 'Background Location Permission',
                        message: 'This app needs access to your location in the background.',
                        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                        buttonPositive: 'OK',
                    }
                );

                if (backgroundLocationGranted !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    Alert.alert('Permission Denied', 'Background location permission is required.');
                    return false;
                }

                return true;

            } catch (err) {
                console.warn(err);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    const sendLocationToServer = async (location) => {
        try {
            console.log('Sending location to server:', location);
            const response = await fetch('https://dummy.com/location', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(location),
            });
            const data = await response.text();
            console.log('Server response:', data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending location to server:', error);
        }
    };

    const veryIntensiveTask = async (taskDataArguments) => {
        const { delay } = taskDataArguments;

        await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            for (let i = 0; BackgroundService.isRunning(); i++) {
                Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    async (position) => {
                        console.log('Location received:', position);
                        const newLocation = {
                            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                            timestamp: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
                        };
                        setLocation(newLocation);
                        await sendLocationToServer(newLocation);
                        console.log('Location dispatched to server:', newLocation);
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        console.error('Error receiving location:', error);
                    },
                    {
                        enableHighAccuracy: true,
                        distanceFilter: 0,
                        interval: 30000,
                        fastestInterval: 15000,
                        forceRequestLocation: true,
                        showLocationDialog: true,
                    }
                );

                await BackgroundService.updateNotification({
                    taskDesc: `Location tracking ${i}`,
                });

                await sleep(delay);
            }
        });
    };

    const options = {
        taskName: 'Location',
        taskTitle: 'Tracking Location',
        taskDesc: 'Tracking your location in the background',
        taskIcon: {
            name: 'ic_launcher',
            type: 'mipmap',
        },
        color: '#ff00ff',
        linkingURI: 'yourapp://location', // Adjust this to match your app's URI scheme
        parameters: {
            delay: 30000, // Set the delay to 30 seconds
        },
        foreground: true,
    };

    const startBackgroundService = async () => {
        const hasLocationPermission = await requestLocationPermission();
        if (!hasLocationPermission) {
            return;
        }

        // Check for battery optimization settings
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            try {
                const isIgnoringOptimization = await BackgroundService.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations();
                if (!isIgnoringOptimization) {
                    await BackgroundService.requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations();
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.warn(err);
            }
        }

        await BackgroundService.start(veryIntensiveTask, options);
        await BackgroundService.updateNotification({ taskDesc: 'Location tracking started' });
        console.log('Background service started');
    };

    const stopBackgroundService = async () => {
        await BackgroundService.stop();
        console.log('Background service stopped');
    };

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Location Tracker</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={startBackgroundService}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Start Background Service</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={stopBackgroundService}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Stop Background Service</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {location.latitude && (
                <Text style={styles.locationText}>
                    Latitude: {location.latitude}, Longitude: {location.longitude}, Time: {location.timestamp}
                </Text>
            )}
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#282C34',
        padding: 20,
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 28,
        color: '#61DAFB',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    button: {
        marginTop: 20,
        paddingVertical: 12,
        paddingHorizontal: 32,
        backgroundColor: '#61DAFB',
        borderRadius: 8,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        elevation: 5,
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: '#282C34',
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '600',
    },
    locationText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        color: 'white',
        marginTop: 20,
    },
});


ANDROID MANIFEST FILE
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>


Honestly I dont even know how to solve this because it is working fine for every other device like other devices with android 14 like pixel 8 or even samsung devices with android version < 14.
Edit:
This is one difference i found while testing on browserStack. When testing on android 14 samsung devices this line gets logged
E/Adreno-AppProfiles(20049): QSPM AIDL service doesn't exist
